# Behavior of pushback

Tags: c++, stl, copy-constructor

I have two method :

```
template <class T>
Matrix<T>::Matrix(int rows, int cols, T* data)

{
 this->nRows = rows;
 this->nCols = cols;

for (int i=0; i < nRows; i++)
{

  vector<T> col(nCols);
     for(int j=0;j<nCols;j++)

      col[j]=*(data+i*nCols+j);

   m.push_back(col);

}
```

}

And for print the matrix:

```
  template <class T>
  void Matrix<T>::Dump(void)
  {
    cout << "\t[\n";
    for (int row=0; row<nRows; row++)
    {
     for (int col=0; col<nCols; col++)
      cout << "\t\t" << m[row][col] << " ";
     cout << "\n";
    }
     cout << "\t]\n";
   }
```

And the test case is :

```
int M[]={1,2,3,3,4,7,2,5,8};
Matrix<int> m(3,3,M);
m.Dump();
```

Scenarios(In constructor) are :

```
  for(int j=0;j<nCols;j++)
     {
      T val(*(data+i*nCols+j));
      col.push_back(val)  ;
        cout<<col[j];
     }
```

The output is all 0.

But

```
for(int j=0;j<nCols;j++)
     {
      T val(*(data+i*nCols+j));
      col[j]=val ;
        cout<<col[j];
     }
```

Gives the correct result.

Please explain why pushback behaves different in both cases ?

Comment: It depends entirely on the type of `col`. Please post _complete_ example code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This

```
 vector<T> col(nCols);
```

line already contracts a column with all zeros in it.
In the first case you push back new value and get something like this

```
[0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3]
```

as the first column. So it is not surprising that

```
cout<<col[j];
```

outputs zeros, because j is not bigger than 2!

Answer (score 1):

Since your call to `col[j]` in the second example succeeds, it looks like you have enough elements in your `vector` to store values for all values of `j` before entering the loop. However, `push_back` adds more elements *to the back of the vector*, past the position at the index `j`. That is why you see all zeros when you print values in the loop. If you change the first example to print

```
cout<<col[col.size()-1];
```

you will see values that you just pushed. They would not be at the same positions as in the first example, though.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like `col` is initially not empty.